# Performance of WordPress Rest API vs WordPress Feeds

Tags: rest-api, feed

I am building and android app using react native for my WordPress blog.

I just want to display the post title, small description, category and featured image on recent 10 posts. All things are in RSS feed also.

So performance wise, the best way is WordPress Rest API or WordPress Feeds?

Comment: I would go for the rest-api. More control.

Comment: I guess it will be the REST APi, but why not just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeds can be easily cached (even put them on CDN), API caching is a more complex thing.
So this covers the performance issue.

But there is also the code and maintenance side... APIs are more flexible as you can change the structure of the request and response to whatever you need and not limeted to a format which you did not design and might not meet all your needs.

Comment: and lets stop calling it REST, there is nothing REST about WordPress's *json* API ;)